# Change_worksheet, Validation Drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, events

I'm having a lot of troubles setting up events (Worksheet_change to be precise), even though I find somewhat similar questions here on this forum:

What I need is:

- Whenever range("D2") is selected/targeted, i want it to unlock the cell and lock it again once it is not selected/targeted
- Also, if lets say "yes" is selected i wan't everything "no" selects to be hidden somehow. If not hidden would it be better if it just made the cells = NoFill & text white?

My code so far (sheet1):

Dropdown

```
Sub Dropdown()

Range("B2") = "structure"
Range("C2") = "Given:"
Range("B2:C2").Interior.Color = RGB(240, 128, 128)

' Dropdown-list
With Range("D2").Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Data!A2:A3"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
Range("D2").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 250, 240)
End With

End Sub
```

My try on unprotecting cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim InputRange As Range
Set InputRange = Range("D2")

Dim MyPassword As String
    MyPassword = "hej"

If Target = Range("D2") Then
        Unprotect Password:=MyPassword
            Target.Locked = False
        Protect Password:=MyPassword
End If
```

If target "Yes"

```
If Target = Range("D2") Then
    Select Case Range("D2").Value
        Case Is = "Yes"
            Range("B4") = "EQ%"
            Range("B5") = "D%"
            Range("B4:B5").Interior.Color = RGB(240, 128, 128)
            Range("C4:C5").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 250, 240)

            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

If target "No"

```
        Case Is = "No"
            Range("E4") = "'+ Virksomhedskapital"
            Range("E5") = "'+ Overkurs ved emission"
            Range("E6") = "'+ Reserve for opskrivning"
            Range("E7") = "'+ Andre reserver"
            Range("E8") = "'+ Overført overskud eller underskud"
            Range("E10") = "'=Equity"
            Range("E4:E8").Interior.Color = RGB(240, 128, 128)
            Range("E10").Interior.Color = RGB(240, 128, 128)
            Range("F4:F8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 250, 240)
            Range("F10").Interior.Color = RGB(135, 206, 250)

            Range("H4") = "'+ Prioritetsgæld"
            Range("H5") = "'+ Bankgæld"
            Range("H6") = "'+ Øvrig rentebærende gæld"
            Range("H7") = "'+ Overskydende likviditet"
            Range("H8") = "'+ Værdipapirer"
            Range("H9") = "'+ Øvrige ikke driftsaktiver"
            Range("H10") = "'= Nettorentebærende gæld"
            Range("H4:H10").Interior.Color = RGB(240, 128, 128)
            Range("I4:I9").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 250, 240)
            Range("I10").Interior.Color = RGB(135, 206, 250)

            Range("B6") = "EQ%"
            Range("B7") = "D%"
            Range("B6:B7").Interior.Color = RGB(240, 128, 128)
            Range("C6:C7").Interior.Color = RGB(135, 206, 250)

            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```

Module1:

```
Sub ProtectAll()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim MyPassword As String

MyPassword = "test"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Protect Password:=MyPassword
Next sh

End Sub

Sub UnprotectAll()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim MyPassword As String

MyPassword = "test"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Unprotect Password:=MyPassword
Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at your code logic, nor attempted to write it, but just checking that you have put the:

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

code into the appropriate Sheet module (Sheet1?), in this event, and not in a normal code module.  You then don't need the reference to 'Test' worksheet in this code.  It is not clear (to me) whether you can't get the event to fire or you can't work out the code to do what you want it to do.

**EDIT FOLLOWING OPs REPLY**

OK, back to first base, try this simple code.  Put it into the **Sheet module** in the **Worksheet_Change** event on the sheet where you have the **data validation list** in cell A1. Set-up cell A1 from the data validation dialogue shown below.  Selecting 'ONE' from the list will color cells C1:C4, 'TWO' will color cells E1:E4 and 'THREE' will 'uncolor' both ranges.  When you have got this working you should be able to modify it to your context.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("A1") Then
        Select Case Range("A1").Value
            Case Is = "ONE"
                Range("C1:C4").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            Case Is = "TWO"
                Range("E1:E4").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            Case Is = "THREE"
                Range("C1:E4").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't really figure out the logic to get the code to fire the way i want it to:

Very shortly described range("A1") is a dropdown list with either yes or no.

i want it to unlock certain cells, and show certain cells if yes, and opposite if it's no i want it to unlock some other cells and show some other cells.

In other words the event depends on your selection in the drop down list.

basically everything is locked and hidden except from the dropdown list, until you enter yes or no.

Comment: @Sebastian Koefoed, please see edit to previous answer.

Comment: Hey got it working, but i'm stuck on the next step. Edited my main question